# FreeForm ViewController - iOS

Tags: ios

I have added another viewcontroller (freeform viewController) on the top of mainviewcontroller, but somehow, it is not showing full size. Please look at my code which is below and screenshots.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    firstSurveyViewController = [[FirstSurveyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstSurveyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    CGRect rect = [firstSurveyViewController.view frame];
    rect.origin.x = 10;
    rect.origin.y = 20;
    [firstSurveyViewController.view  setFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:firstSurveyViewController.view];
}
```

[image: firstSurveyViewController]

[image]

Comment: Try doing this in viewDidAppear instead. Frames (other than self.frame) are not yet set in viewDidLoad. Also, adding the view of another view controller like this is not a good idea unless you make it a child view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting with width and height in addition to the origin, manually. What is the initial value of `rect` after `CGRect rect = [firstSurveyViewController.view frame];`?

Also, in general, you don't really want to add viewControllers to other viewControllers unless you're using a `UINavigationController` or `UIViewController Containment` to manage them. Seems like in this case `firstSurveyViewController` should just be `firstSurveyView`, a subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: [firstSurveyViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,300,440)]; , still same.